# Copying figure from Word to LaTeX

Tags: graphics

I have a figure drawn in Word. I would like to include this in my LaTeX document without redrawing it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, add more details; describe, what happens, exactly; add warnings and/or errors from the LaTeX compile run. A complete, as minimal as possible, example, which can be run by others, would be useful to show the problem.

Comment: @Robert I don't think we know enough to judge whether it is a duplicate of that question. That one is much more specific and concerns a specific problem with a particular format of image exported from Word.

Comment: I suggest a pdf conversion with `open office`, a `krop` cut and finally a `\includegraphics`.

Comment: There are online tools that can extract bitmap graphics from pdf documents — and maybe from Word documents.

Answer (score 3):

This method was what I taught college calculus students.

1. Draw the picture using Word (although you can start in PowerPoint)
2. Now do an extended select of all the picture elements. (i.e. hold the control key down and left click on EVERY element of the picture)
3. Now (very important) be sure the cursor is hovering over one of the elements of the picture and then press `Cntl-C` for copy.
4. Next open PowerPoint and paste, `Cntl-V`, this at an empty place in any frame.
5. Now (again important) be sure the cursor is hovering over one of the elements of the picture and press the RIGHT mouse button.
6. In the pop-up menu select `Save-as-Picture`.
7. Save as an `*.png' in the same folder as your`*.tex`file`.
8. Finally you can use `\includegraphics{basefilename}` where `basefilename` is just the base of the full file name of the picture `*.png`.  (you must have `\usepackage{graphicx}` in the preamble).

**A.** Copy the image you have made.

**B.** paste it on Microsoft Visio. Now there may be some problem here as Visio sometimes does not take word images. so go to the top bar into 'edit'. then into 'paste special'. A list will pop up. Select 'Picture(Enhanced Metafile)'.

**C.** Save this Visio file as *.png.

Comment: This first method worked great for me - thx!

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a strategy that combines the best features of some of the other answers.

- Select all the elements of your picture - as R. Schumacher suggests -
  and *group* them.
- Go to save -> save as type - save as PDF (not save as Adobe PDF from the
  top save menu).
- Under Options, check save selection.
- Save and view.

You may want to use `pdfcrop` to remove whitespace before you include the figure in your document. `pdfcrop` comes with your TeX distribution.

Comment: Is it really necessary to group all elements first? It worked for me without this step.

Comment: @HåkonMarthinsen My figure had several pieces overlaid. I think I needed to group.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is open the 
Word document with LibreOffice, and save document as ODT. Then, rename this file as ZIP file. In this archive, you will see the image you are looking for, that you can use it. Normally, appears in PNG format.

Comment: The final pass is insert it in your LaTeX document, as R. Schumacher says in point 8 of his answer.

Comment: This method only works if the image in Word was originally a graphic file.  In this case the O.P. had used the Word drawing tools to create an image. When you open in LibreOffice it still is a set of separate graphic images.  And the multilayer diagram is not stored by LibreOffice as a *.png.   If, however, the Word document has a large number of graphic images (imported to Word from a graphic format such at *.gif, *.bmp, *.jpg, *.png) then this approach will generate all the images as *.png's at once.

Answer (score 1):

Try to take a screen shot and float the figure.

Comment: A screenshoot may result in a lower quality.  Please explain better ...

Answer (score 0):

I tried it using powerpoint.The diagram alone pasted in the ppt and converted to pdf and that added to my latex,it works fine.

Comment: I hope there wasn't text in the figure because it's more than likely going to be the wrong font and difficult to scale.